How to identify input fields in unstructured PDFs using Python
I am trying to parse an unstructured PDF file and extract information about some input fields like radiobuttons, but I am not sure how to do that.
I tried using get_fields from PyPDF2, it does not return anything because of the nature of the PDF.
When I use extract_text() it just gives "YES" or "NO" for the radiobutton components. Also when i print the full extracted text, there's often random spaces in between the words.Is there any method of accurately parsing unstructured PDF files?

Hi, I have some idea but I can not say how it is but if you share a pdf file I will try to test at local then I will provide a code snipped.

sure @Cappittall , but how do I share it, since i cant upload PDFs here

Add it to your Google drive and give it link. Or send me an email: netcat16@gmail.com

@Cappittall sent you an email

I received, after trials let you know soon.

that's not a visual task. PDFs with form fields are data, not a picture.

I tried the way @jaco-kemp, but its not working. However, here one solution and works good for the pdf which you shared with me. But I am not sure is it going to work with others as it is little dirty :)) :
import fitz
import cv2
import numpy as np

def extract_radio_button_info(pdf_path):
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    for page_num in range(len(doc)):
        print('-' * 100)
        print('Page number:', page_num)
        page = doc[page_num]
        text = page.get_text("text")
        lines = text.splitlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if "SOUR SERVICE (PER NACE MR-01-75)" in line:
                text_instances = page.search_for("SOUR SERVICE (PER NACE MR-01-75)")
                if text_instances:
                    print(i, line)
                    for ii, text_rect in enumerate(text_instances):
                        print('Y coordinate:', text_rect.y1)
                        # Convert PDF page to image
                        pix = page.get_pixmap(alpha=False)
                        img = np.frombuffer(pix.samples, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(pix.height, pix.width, pix.n)
                        # Find radio button coordinates
                        radio_button_x = text_rect.x1 + 50  # Adjust the offset as needed
                        radio_button_y = text_rect.y1
                        # Extract the radio button regions from the image
                        yes_button_region = img[int(radio_button_y - 7):int(radio_button_y + 1),
                                             int(radio_button_x + 20):int(radio_button_x + 30)]
                        no_button_region = img[int(radio_button_y - 7):int(radio_button_y + 1),
                                            int(radio_button_x + 75):int(radio_button_x + 85)]
                        # Save the radio button regions for visualization (optional)
                        cv2.imwrite(f'yes_button_region.png', yes_button_region)
                        cv2.imwrite(f'no_button_region.png', no_button_region)
                        # Calculate the mean pixel intensity for each region
                        yes_mean_intensity = cv2.mean(yes_button_region)[0]
                        no_mean_intensity = cv2.mean(no_button_region)[0]
                        # Determine the selected option based on the darker region
                        if yes_mean_intensity < no_mean_intensity:
                            selected_option = "YES"
                        else:
                            selected_option = "NO"
                        print(f"Selected option: {selected_option}")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    pdf_path = "data/sample.pdf"
    extract_radio_button_info(pdf_path)


maybe you should add that you used computer vision approach since not mentioned in the tags of the question. Probably best solution in this case:)

Thank you, this was very helpful. In this code I've used pytesseract.image_to_string(), resized the image and denoised the image to print the value of the radiobutton without explicitly writing it in the if blocks

If you're not set on using PyPDF2, you could consider using PyMuPDF. A field is a "widget", and you can iterate over the widgets in a document (or page in a document) to extract the text. The code below should work. Here I am printing the field value for each field on each page of a pdf stored in "filepath":
import fitz

document = fitz.open(filepath)
for page_number in range(document.page_count):
    page = document[page_number]
    for widget in page.widgets():
        print(widget.field_value)

Credit to JorjMcKie in this post for helping me with the same issue.
EDIT:
Seeing as your document doesn't seem to have actual fields, you could go the more brute force way and print out the text line by line:
import fitz

document = fitz.open(filepath)
for page_number in range(document.page_count):
    page = document[page_number]
    text = page.get_text("text")
    for i, line in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
        print(f"Line {i}: {line}")

Assuming all your pdfs have the same structure, you could then identify the line numbers that contain the "field" data you are interested in, and store them in a list (e.g. [15, 30, 47]). Once you have this, you can extract the desired lines from your PDF:
import fitz

index_list = [15, 30, 47]
document = fitz.open(filepath)
lines = []
for page_number in range(document.page_count):
    page = document[page_number]
    text = page.get_text("text")
    for i, line in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
        if i in index_list:
            lines.append(line)

Not very elegant, and it assumes that all your pdfs have the same structure, but hopefully it helps!

Tried this snippet with my file, its not printing anything. From what I understand it cant recognise the fields/widgets due to the unstructured nature of the PDF

Ah, I'm sorry. Hopefully Capittall has the answer for you. You're welcome to email it to me at jkemp@sun.ac.za as well, and I'll have a look. Not sure I've ever worked with unstructured pdfs before.

No worries, and sure have a look at it, I'll email you.
